# "disabled for fips" error getting thrown when trying to execute a js file with the "--force-fips" flag

Tags: node.js, fips

I see the following error get thrown when trying to run node with the --force-fips flag:

```
Error: disabled for fips
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:158:19)
    at Server (_tls_wrap.js:803:25)
    at new Server (https.js:54:14)
    at Object.createServer (https.js:76:10)
    at Object.module.exports.startServer
```

Following the stack-trace, I was able to figure out that the error get thrown when the ["loadPKCS12" method](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v8.x/lib/_tls_common.js#L158) gets executed. (I am passing a keystore to the "pfx" parameter along with the keystore password corresponding to the "passphrase" parameter as part of the [options object when bringing up the "https" server instance](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options)).

The [method definition](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v8.x/src/node_crypto.cc#L1179) is in c++ and I am finding it hard to debug the issue. What could the issue be? Could it be an issue with the keystore that I am passing?

I am making use of node v8.9.4 and I am trying this out on a centos machine (centos-release-7-4.1708.el7.centos.x86_64 to be specific)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be an issue with the certificate that I was making use of. The certificate was encrypted using an algorithm which was fips in-compliant (40-bit RC2). Generating the certificate (using openssl) by passing in the -descert argument fixed the issue for me (Passing in the descert argument while generating the certificate encrypts the certificate using Triple DES which is fips compliant).

Reference: https://community.rsa.com/docs/DOC-51951